# Accessing this.$() in qunit test

Tags: javascript, ember.js, qunit

I’ve created a small mixin that helps a component to be hidden when the user clicks outside of the component. I’d now like to add a test for it, where I trigger a click event outside a component that extends the mixin.

All I want to test is that a method called `onOutsideClick` is called. For this, I’m trying to draw inspiration from: 
https://github.com/nucleartide/ember-outside-click

But when I do this:

```
const HideOnOutsideClickObject = Ember.Component.extend(HideOnOutsideClick, {
})

test('click outside', function(assert) {
  const element = this.$()[0]

  const event = document.createEvent('MouseEvent')
  event.initEvent(event, true, true)
  element.dispatchEvent(event)

  assert.ok(HideOnOutsideClickObject.onOutsideClick)
})
```

I get an error saying that `this.$() is not a function`. What am I missing?

I’ve of course imported the mixin as I should.

Comment: is this a component integration test?

Comment: It's a component unit test

Comment: for components I would recommend integration tests. Your test-case could be solved perfectly.

Comment: `this` inside your test is not going to be the same `this` as inside the Component. You need to get a reference to the component instance inside the test, or if you just need the element, then select it using the global jQuery method.